# Construct div pattern using Ajax Json

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, json

I'm going to use [owl carosel](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/).In the hardcoded div's working.Now i want to get this type via ajax function.I'll try to do this in several ways but not success.

My Webmethod it returns the Image Path & Caption values.

```
<div id="owl-demo">
            <div class="item"><a class="item link"><img src="/Content/images/sdfdfd.png" alt="Owl Image"></a><p><center>CAPTION</center></p></div>
            <div class="item"><a class="item link"><img src="/Content/images/tyty.png" alt="Owl Image"></a><p><center>CAPTION</center></p></div>
</div>
```

My Ajax function(instead of that hardcoded values )

```
   function GetAllImages()
{

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Dest/GetAllImages",
        success: function (msg) {
            debugger;
            if (msg._allImg.length > 0) {
                $.each(msg._allImg, function (index, item) {
                   //In here i need to construct that above pattern
                    //My Webmethod it returns the Image Path & Caption values.


                      var html = $("<div>").html();
                      var html2 = $("<img src").html();
                      $('#owl-demo').append(html);
                });

            }
            else {

            }


        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I follow you, I think you mean:

```
$('#owl-demo').append('<div class="item"><a class="item link"><img src="/Content/images/' +
    item.url + '" alt="Owl Image"></a><p><center>' +
    item.caption + '</center></p></div>');
```

Comment: lets say we have 15 images.. Using this code it's overrried and only it shows 1 image know ?

Comment: No, because you are using `append()`. Assuming you are inside `$.each()`, it'll loop trough `item` and add more `div`s.

Comment: When i get it thisone to a variable like var x = $('#owl-demo').append ..... then it shows [object Object] and not showing that div patterns.